# python - how to convert a list of size n to a 2d numpy array of size n/2 x n/2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

for instance 
converting 
    [
          3, 1, 2, 4,
          4, 2, 3, 1,
          1, 3, 4, 2,
          2, 4, 1, 3
     ]
to

```
[
      [3, 1, 2, 4],
      [4, 2, 3, 1],
      [1, 3, 4, 2],
      [2, 4, 1, 3]
]
```

shortest method ... not converting it into 4 lists then to 2d

Comment: You are looking for `numpy.reshape`, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: I think you'd want to convert a list of size `n*n` to an `n by n` array...

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you can convert a 1d array to a 2d array by using the `reshape` command. The first argument is your current array, and the second one specifies what the new 'shape' of it should look like. In this case, 4 rows by 4 columns.

```
import numpy as np

my_array = [ 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3 ]
new_array = np.reshape(my_array, (4, 4))
```

will result in `new_array` being:

```
array([[3, 1, 2, 4],
       [4, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 4, 2],
       [2, 4, 1, 3]])
```

[Akavall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078084/akavall) was kind enough to link directly to the docs page on the `reshape` command, copying here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html